# Button stretched on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a button that unfolds when tapped by user unveiling a text label. It works fine however, I have two issues:

- I can't get the text in the button to be perfectly centered. It's very strange, when I decrease `line-height` to 0% the text actually goes down.
- The button gets stretched on mobile for some reason ([on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me7Mv.png) vs [on computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVqTe.png))

**Code below** (Please forgive me, I am a HTML n00b)

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    var y = document.getElementById('myDIV2');

    var elem = document.getElementById("btn");

    if (x.style.opacity == 1) {
      x.style.opacity = 0;
      y.style.opacity = 0
      elem.innerHTML = "+";
    } else {
      x.style.opacity = 1;
      y.style.opacity = 1;
      elem.innerHTML = "-";
    }
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate
{
      0%   {border-color: #fff;}
      50%  {border-color: #FF6B35;}
      100% {border-color: #fff;}
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

.myDIV {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    font-family: "Verdana";
}
.btn {

  font-size: 200%;
  display:block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px white solid;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 10%;
  animation: pulsate 2s infinite;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Verdana";

}

.vertical-line{
      width: 0px; /* Use only border style */
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid white; /* This is default border style for <hr> tag */
      margin: 0 auto;
      opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="myDIV" id="myDIV">This is my DIV element.</div>

<div class="vertical-line" id="myDIV2" style="height: 90px;"></div>

<button class="btn" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">+</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-box`. Makes vertically and horizontally aligning elements easier. Check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for a simple guide.

On your `.btn` CSS selector, change/add the following properties and values:

```
font-size: 200%;
display: block;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px white solid;
color: white;
background-color: transparent;
margin: 0 auto;
line-height: 0%;
animation: pulsate 2s infinite;
outline: none;
font-family: "Verdana";
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

And to prevent it from stretching add a `max-width` property and value

```
max-width: 50px;
```

This should solve both errors.